# How to transfer large TSV file in Postgre database through R

Tags: r, postgresql, csv

I have a large TSV file of 20 Go located on a given server. I need to charge the data into a PostGreSQL database located into another server.

Usually, I am using a R interface on the first server, in which the TSV file is located, to transfer the file to the PostGreSQL data base.

- I tried to charge directly the tsv file through the PostGre interface but it is not working with tsv file (only csv apprently) ;
- I have tried to open the file in R from the serveur but I have issued with virtual memories.

This is what I am using in R:

```
##############################################################################
# Database connection
##############################################################################

# define driver
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

# set up connection to existing PostgreSQL database, just plug in own details

con <- dbConnect(drv,
             dbname = "mydatabase",
             host = "(my server adress)",
             port = "5432",
             user = "XXX", password = "XXX")
 ##############################################################################
# File loading
 ##############################################################################

 data2<-as.data.frame(fread("/myfile"))
 dbWriteTable(con, "My_data",data2,append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
  Opened 20.19GB (21680897784 bytes) file ok but could not memory map it. This is a 64bit process. There is probably not enough contiguous virtual memory available.
```

Comment: Epic amount of data! Consider Postgres' [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) or psql's [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) fast text file, bulk importers and avoid R as middle layer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that R supports non-memory resident dataframes (as standard anyway).  So if the data doesn't fit into R's memory, you can't use R's "dbWriteTable".

It doesn't look like you are doing statistical transforms or anything like that inside R, so you perhaps should just use psql's \copy.  Then you will miss out on fread's inference of delimiter and types, so this may take some fiddling to get it to work exactly the same.

```
psql -c '\copy "My_data" from /myfile'
```

Also, it looks like dbWriteTable will create the table if it does not already exist, which \copy does not do, so that will take some more fiddling.

> I tried to charge directly the tsv file through the PostGre interface but it is not working with tsv file (only csv apprently) ;

You have not shown us anything that would enable us to help you with this problem.  What did you try?  What error did you get?  Does your file need escaping, and if so how is it done?  With COPY or \copy, you can either use text format (which uses backslashes to escape things which need escaping), or you can use CSV format but then specify a tab as delimiter `with (format csv, delimiter E'\t')`, in which case special characters are escaped by quoting them rather than backwhacking them.

Comment: I am really sorry @jianes but I am still struggling with the importation in the SQL database. I tried what you advice with COPY but I get an error: "ERROR: not able to open the file XXXX for reading : no file or directory of that type (I am using the french version so this is translation)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. I tried using postGre SQL directly but still not working.

```
COPY "table_name" FROM 'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\"filename".tsv' DELIMITER '\t'
```

I previously created the table of course.

I have the following error :

```
ERROR:  ERREUR:  le délimiteur COPY doit être sur un seul caractère sur un octet

SQL state: 0A000
```

Comment: `'\t'` is two characters, a backslash, and a t.  You would want `E'\t'`, which is one character, a tab.  Also, there is no reason to specify a delimiter, as tab is the default when you don't don't specify a format.

Comment: Also, having `"filename "`in doublequotes, if that is what you literally have, would not work.

Comment: And finally, if you use COPY then the file needs to be on (or accessible to) the database server.  If the file is on the same machine from which you are running psql, then you would use \copy, not COPY.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The file is on my machine so I tried to use `\copy` and to launch the following query: `\copy npl FROM 'C:\Users\[myname]\Documents\[myfile].tsv'` but it is not working. I get `error of syntax`